# Copying value from a matching id and appending to a new column

Tags: python, pandas

```
joinable_id id  title   owner_id    user_id country
0   ffff8f7f-7233-4a79-a651-ec499d0ca888    ffff8f7f-7233-4a79-a651-ec499d0ca888    doctor  4251311 4251311 US
1   ffff8f7f-7233-4a79-a651-ec499d0ca888    ffff8f7f-7233-4a79-a651-ec499d0ca888    doctor  4251311 4251314 US
2   ffff8f7f-7233-4a79-a651-ec499d0ca888    ffff8f7f-7233-4a79-a651-ec499d0ca888    doctor  4251311 4251315 US
```

I have a dataset of projects that is structured as above.
I need to make a new column of destination countries where the conditions are as such:

Check the **owner id** of the project (**joinable id**), go to that row and copy the **country**, append it to the current row's **destination** column.

Is this possible to do with Python and Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

A self join is approach (would be in SQL too).  However you have duplicate keys
so a few more steps

- remove same row to same row `.loc[lambda d: d["index"]!=d["index_"]]`
- take the `first()` matching row

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""joinable_id id  title   owner_id    user_id country
0   ffff8f7f-7233-4a79-a651-ec499d0ca888    ffff8f7f-7233-4a79-a651-ec499d0ca888    doctor  4251311 4251311 US
1   ffff8f7f-7233-4a79-a651-ec499d0ca888    ffff8f7f-7233-4a79-a651-ec499d0ca888    doctor  4251311 4251314 US
2   ffff8f7f-7233-4a79-a651-ec499d0ca888    ffff8f7f-7233-4a79-a651-ec499d0ca888    doctor  4251311 4251315 US"""), sep="\s+")

(df.reset_index().merge(df.loc[:,["id","country"]].reset_index(), left_on="joinable_id", right_on="id", suffixes=("","_"))
 .drop(columns="id_")
 .loc[lambda d: d["index"]!=d["index_"]]
 .groupby("index", as_index=False).first()
 .drop(columns="index_")
 .rename(columns={"country_":"destination"})
)
```